# What do $SU(N)$ Dynkin labels say about a multi-component bosonic wavefunction?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, group-theory, representation-theory, bosons

Suppose you have a system of A bosons of $N$ different types, each of which can be in different angular momentum orbitals. We define the creation operator of a boson of type $a$ with angular momentum $k$ by $ b_{a,k}^\dagger $. 
A basis for the states of such bosons with angular momentum $ L $ can then be created by acting with a products of  $ b_{a,k}^\dagger $s on the vacuum state in such a way that the total angular momentum is correct.

Suppose now that the Hamiltonian (including interaction) is $SU(N)$
 symmetric (i.e. homogeneous - same interaction between every pair of particles) and commutes with the total angular momentum operator. We then know that the eigenstates can be labelled by SU(N)-quantum numbers (called Dynkin labels, I think).

**My question is: what are these numbers and how do they reflect the symmetries of the corresponding eigenstates?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Dynkin labels $(\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\ldots,\lambda_{N-1})$ label irreducible representations of $SU(N)$.  Using Young diagrams and Schur-Weyl duality is it possible to infer the permutation symmetry properties of the multiparticle states from the Dynkin labels.

These, however, will not help you get angular momentum labels $L$.  For these you need branching rules from an irrep $(\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\ldots,\lambda_{N-1})$ to the $SO(3)$ subgroup of rotations.  The branching rules are usually clarified using a subgroup chain, i.e. something like
$$
SU(N)\supset SO(N)\supset SO(N-1)\ldots \supset SO(3)\tag{1}
$$
with each link in the chain supplying quantum numbers to properly label your states.

The problem is actually highly non-trivial.  For $SU(3)\supset SO(3)$ the branching rules are known from the work of Elliott on the nuclear $SU(3)$ model, and actually constructing basis states is extremely non-trivial as some $SO(3)$ irreps will usually occur more than once.  For example, in the irrep $(3,2)$, one can find the $SO(3)$ irreps $L=1,2,3,3,4,5$ with $L=3$ occurring twice.

Of course the subgroup chain of Eq.(1) is not the only way to get to $SO(3)$, i.e one could use $SU(N)\supset SU(N-1)\ldots SU(3)\supset SO(3)$.  This chain and the labels it supplies will have a different physical interpretation than the chain of (1).

The place to look are the tables of the review article by Slansky: *Group theory for unified model building*, Phys.Rep. vol. 79 (1981) p.1-128.  The physics of the simplest subgroup chains is best explained in nuclear physics texts, and a good modern one is the one by Rowe and Wood.  Otherwise, the actual first principle computation use modified tableaux and Schur functions, which are not for the faint-at-hearts.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Suppose I know the angular momentum of the eigenstate, i.e. no need to get it from the Dynkin labels. What then do I know about the symmetries of the eigenstate? Example: If I have a system of 4 bosons with L=3 and an eigenstate has Dynkin labels (1,1), i.e. 3 species, what does this say about the symmetries of the eigenstate?

Comment: I'm not sure I know how to answer because in general one does not start with $L$ values but with an irrep $(\lambda,\mu)$ and decomposes the n-fold tensor product.  Thus, if your particles are in the same shell (say the $N=3$ shell, which is the lowest one containing $L=3$ states), then you would need to decompose the tensor product $(3,0)\otimes(3,0)\otimes(3,0)\otimes(3,0)$ and see how many and where  the various (1,1) irreps fall in term of permutation symmetry.   This is a tedious job best done using Schur functions and plethysms but maybe your example can be worked out by hand.